# Description of Perl hash syntax in use statements

Tags: perl

In Perl the following is allowed

```
use constant MY_CONSTANT => 1
```

however this does not match the documentation of "use" which states that it can take a list. The above is however not a list in the normal way as shown by the following command.

```
perl -e 'use strict; my @l = "test" => 1; print "@l\n"
```

This will print "test" and not "test 1".

So is this some special list syntax that can be used together with the use statement or is it also allowed in other cases?

Comment: Using `use warnings;` (or `-w`) would have given you a hint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**`MY_CONSTANT => 1` isn't "a hash".**

The `=>` is essentially just a comma, with the additional property that a “bareword” on the left side will be autoquoted: `foo => 42` is exactly the same as `'foo', 42`. Therefore we can do silly stuff like `foo => bar => baz => 42`. The “fat comma” should be used to indicate a relation between the left and the right value, e.g. between a hash key and value.

**`LIST` in `use Module LIST` doesn't mean you need to use the list operator**

`LIST` simply refers to an arbitrary expression that will be evaluated in list context, so not only does list operator `MY_CONSTANT => 1` match the specified syntax, but so would the following:

```
 sub f { MY_CONSTANT => 1 }
 use constant f();
```

**Be wary of precedence**

The next problem you're running into is that the `=` operator has higher precedence than `,`:

```
my @array = 1, 2, 3;
```

parses as

```
(my @array = 1), 2, 3;
```

As `=>` is the same as `,`, the line `my @array = test => 1;` will parse as

```
(my @array = "test"), 1;
```

Use parens to indicate the correct precedence:

```
my @array = (test => 1);
```

which will produce your expected output.

Comment: Ahh the joys of Perl syntax special cases :) Glad it had a decent explanation though.

Comment: @oyse: It's not a special case. `=>` behaves the same everywhere.

Comment: Added what `LIST` means in the syntax description of functions.

Comment: @Borodin Well, that depends a little on how you view it :) Normally I would expect a Perl list to start with qw or ( and in the module import that is not required. For me that is a special cases since I can't remember to have seen that syntax anywhere and I couldn't find the documentation for the syntax. Note that the question is not about the =>, but about the lack of qw or (.